# Mail.app - all history unavailable

Tags: icloud, mail.app, catalina, ms-office

I attempted to use Mail.app with iCloud and Outlook accounts after clean install of macOS 10.15.7 was performed on my Mac mini (late 2012).

After setting the accounts, I found no messages on any account were displayed. “Rebuild” option did not solve the issue. Deleted and setup the accounts again with the same result.

I am under the impression all my eMail messages (Inbox, Sent, Junk, Trash) on the servers were lost... Is this even possible, I wonder?!

At present I can send and receive messages using all my accounts, BUT all history (many years of it!) appears lost. Devastated, to say the least...

Please help!

P.S. No Time Machine backup available (I know, I know…), unfortunately enough.

Comment: So you log into Outlook on the web, and nothing is there?  Into iCloud.com, and nothing is there?

Comment: Thank you Marc! Yes, when I log into Outlook on the web, I see nothing is there for all my Outlook accounts. The situation is the same when I log into iCloud.com.

Comment: Then the mail is gone, unless you have been backing them up.